# Cannot generate random value for __security_cookie in custom CRT

Tags: c, windows, clang, msvcrt, crt

While implementing my own C runtime solution for applications for Windows OS, I faced the following problem:

Each execution time `__security_cookie` should get a random value with the **selectany** attribute (using `__declspec(selectany)`). But it doesn't... And because of this every time it has the default value of `0x00002B992DDFA232` in a 64-bit version of the application. And it causes an error (Global security check fails).

I use Clang version 14 for compiling my code.

***GlobalSecurity.c:***

```
#if defined (_WIN64)
    #define DEFAULT_SECURITY_COOKIE 0x00002B992DDFA232
#else
    #define DEFAULT_SECURITY_COOKIE 0xBB40E64E
#endif

// Global security cookie
__declspec(selectany) UPtr __security_cookie = (UPtr)DEFAULT_SECURITY_COOKIE;
__declspec(selectany) UPtr __security_cookie_complement = ~((UPtr)DEFAULT_SECURITY_COOKIE);
```

***GlobalSecurity.h***

```
...
// Global security cookie
extern UPtr __security_cookie;
extern UPtr __security_cookie_complement;


typedef union
{
    unsigned __int64 ft_scalar;
    FILETIME ft_struct;
} FT;

// Initializes global security cookie
void CDECL __security_init_cookie()
{
    if (__security_cookie != DEFAULT_SECURITY_COOKIE
#if defined (_M_IX86)
        && (__security_cookie & 0xFFFF0000) != 0
#endif
        )
    {
        __security_cookie_complement = ~__security_cookie;
        return;
    }
...
```

Why does not `__security_cookie` work as it should? And how this problem can be solved?

P.S.: UPtr is the same as UINT_PTR

Comment: Why do you think selectany should give you a random value?

Comment: @Anders, I thought so until I read the documentation

Comment: The code snippets are merely a copy/paste from the Microsoft CRT source code, it isn't useful to guess what went wrong.  Most obvious possible mishap is that it doesn't run or runs too late, getting it done as part of the CRT initialization is crucial.  Done with #pragma init_seg(compiler) in MSVCRT, the kind of implementation detail that never translates well to another compiler.

Comment: Ok. I will try also to make it using ``#pragma init_seg(...)``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`selectany` does not give you a random number and even if its purpose was to avoid "using uninitialized variable" warnings, your code is assigning to the variable!

The `selectany` attribute allows the same global variable to be declared and initialized in multiple translation units.

Comment: Understood. But looking through one special test executable with standard MSVCRT I found out that ``__security_cookie`` gets every time a random value. How can this be made?

Comment: In your custom CRT, before you call the users main(), initialize the cookie using real crypto or `GetTickCount` or whatever.